# Regex to match content in last set of brackets, regardless of how many empty or filled brackets there are

Tags: javascript, regex

Really struggling with this... trying to write a regex that pulls out the content in the last set of brackets even if there is no content (blank string). If it's helpful, the brackets will not nest inside one another.

Examples:

```
[][] => ""
[][a] => "a"
[a][] => ""
"a" => null
[][a][c][d][b] => "b"
ad[a][c][d] => "d"
[a][ra]dds[c] => "c"
```

Comment: Last set of brackets, but in your sample `[a][] => "a"` regex should return a. From what I understood, it should be a zero length.

Comment: yes that was an error on my part!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves your problem in one go without having to recheck the string:

```
var re = /.*\[([^\]]*)\]/;
```

The reason why this works is because the `.*` is greedy and will select everything up until the last instance of `[ (anything but "]") ]`, with this last instance being the match. Thus, match `1` will have your expected result.

Here's the railroad diagram:

[image]

Here's the [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eI3nL3/2).

And here is a Stack Snippet of the test strings and match strings:

```js
var testStrings = ['[][]', '[][a]', '[a][]', 'a', '[][a][c][d][b]', 'ad[a][c][d]', '[a][ra]dds[c]', '[a][ra]dasdf[c]asdf', '[][][]asdf', '[][]asdf][]', '[][a][asdfas][awef]asdf][]'];

var re = /.*\[([^\]]*)\]/;

testStrings.forEach(function(str) {
    var res = str.match(re) && str.match(re)[1]; /* re.exec(str) instead of str.match(re) also works */
    document.querySelector('.matchString').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div>Match String: <span class='results'>${res}</span></div>`);

  document.querySelector('.testString').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div>Test String: <span class='results'>${str}</span></div>`);
});
```

```css
.testString {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}

.matchString {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  float: right;
}

.results {
  font-weight: bold;
  
}
```

```html
<div class='testString'></div>
<div class='matchString'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not go with something simple:

```
var re = /\[([^\]]+)\]/gim;
```

Looking back on it, it looks like a jumble of brackets. But it just finds two brackets and captures the character(s) inside them.

To find the last match, you just iterate through the array of matches.

If there is no match, but you still want to know if there are any empty brackets, you can JS's built in functions for strings. (I think it's `indexOf("[]")`). That will be faster than doing a regex.

Simple!

Comment: This doesn't solve matching the `[][]` condition as OP wishes to differentiate from a non-match `"a" => null`

Comment: @timolawl Nice catch! I'm not very familiar with JS, but I think that my edit should cover everything now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var re = /\[([^[]*)\]$/;
```

This is similar to @Laurel's solution, but uses `$` to find the last set of brackets directly, and allows it to be empty.